# How to write a function to obtain the types of elements in an array in postgresql 12.0?

Tags: arrays, string, postgresql

Suppose one has an array

```
{"11.2 ounces","English","Null","100"}
```

How to write a function to obtain the type of element, and get the following output as a text type?:

```
('11.2 ounces','English',Null,100)
```

Comment: All elements of an array (must) have the same type. So I am not sure what you are asking for. If the array is declared as `text[]` then all elements are `text`